# Python RSA encryption

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, rsa

I am trying to write a RSA encryption software tool that will use the same key every single time. here is what I have so far.

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

key = <_RSAobj @0x24b6348 n<1024>,e,d,p,q,u,private>
publickey = key.publickey()
encrypted = publickey.encrypt('hi', 32)
print(encrypted)
```

I get a syntax error at line 5 pointing at the < sign. I know that this is a valid private key. what is the problem and how do I fix it. Also I am using python 2.7.3

[EDIT] I get the key from this code

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import os
random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
print(key)
raw_input()
```

Also I am getting a 'RSA key format not supported error' from this code after the 'raw_input()'

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
text_file = open("keyfile.txt", "w")
text_file.write('<_RSAobj @0x24b6348 n<1024>,e,d,p,q,u,private>')
text_file.close()
raw_input()
with open('keyfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    externKey = f.readline()
key = RSA.importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)
publickey = key.publickey()
encrypted = publickey.encrypt('hi', 32)
print(encrypted)
```

Comment: That's not a valid key. That's a string representation of a key object.

Comment: how can I convert a string into a key object??

Comment: `RSA.importKey("key string here")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `<_RSAobj @0x24b6348 n<1024>,e,d,p,q,u,private>` is not a valid key, not sure how you get this, but it is a string representation of your key as  a `Python` object only, **the actual key content is not presented, also note that you cannot rebuild the key object with this string representation**.

Before you do RSA encrypt with your key, you should import your key from some place like **File**, **Generating In Memory** etc.

So what you should do is:

```
key = RSA.importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)
```

Where the `externKey` is a String, so you can load the key string from your key **File** with this way.

**Or**:

```
key = RSA.generate(bits, randfunc=None, progress_func=None, e=65537)
```

Where the `bits` is the strength of your key, e.g 2048.

Either way you will have an RSA key object (`_RSAobj`) returned, then you can do encryption as the rest of your code did.

**[EDIT] Complete Code**

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

#Quick way to generate a new key
private_key = RSA.generate(1024)

#Show the real content of the private part to console, be careful with this!
print(private_key.exportKey())

#Get the public part
public_key = private_key.publickey()

#Show the real content of the public part to console
print(public_key.exportKey())

#Save both keys into some file for future usage if needed
with open("rsa.pub", "w") as pub_file:
    pub_file.write(public_key.exportKey())

with open("rsa.pvt", "w") as pvt_file:
    pvt_file.write(private_key.exportKey())

#Load public key back from file and we only need public key for encryption
with open('rsa.pub', 'r') as pub_file:
    pub_key = RSA.importKey(pub_file.read())

#Encrypt something with public key and print to console
encrypted = pub_key.encrypt('hello world', None) # the second param None here is useless
print(encrypted)

#Load private key back from file and we must need private key for decryption
with open('rsa.pvt', 'r') as pvt_file:
    pvt_key = RSA.importKey(pvt_file.read())

#Decrypt the text back with private key and print to console
text = pvt_key.decrypt(encrypted)
print(text)
```

Comment: `<_RSAobj @0x24b6348 n<1024>,e,d,p,q,u,private>`  this is not your key, just a string representation. you cannot rebuild the key object with this string representation.

Comment: Already provided the complete code for generating, storing, loading, and encrypting.

Comment: so in a unencrypter python file, like bellow 
'decrypted = key.decrypt(message)' would I use the public key or the private key given

Comment: Decryption must use private key given

Comment: This scripts pops up a list index out of range error in line 12. Any ideas??

Comment: Yeah, thanks for reminding, already fixed, and added the decryption example.

Comment: i get an error when I change line 5 to private_key = RSA.importKey(key). the error is still a index error. any ideas?